# Why am I getting empty string as an extra factor in my target class?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm writing code to test a bunch of machine learning models on a test data set. Some of the rows in my target class have empty strings, so I wrote some code to get rid of these rows.

```
data <- read.csv("ML17-TP2-train.csv", header = TRUE)
filtered_data <- data[!(data$gender==" " | data$gender==""),]
train_data <- filtered_data[1:1200, c(3,4,6,7,8)]
test_data <- filtered_data[15001:17000, c(3,4,6,7,8)]
```

I then used MLR to train and test a machine learning model

```
#create the task
nb.task <- makeClassifTask(id = "NaiveBayes", data = nb.data, target = "gender")

#create the learning
nb.learner <- makeLearner("classif.naiveBayes", predict.type = "prob", fix.factors.prediction = TRUE)

#train the learner
nb.trained <- train(nb.learner, nb.task)

#predict
nb.predict <- predict(nb.trained, newdata = test_data)

#get the auc
performance(nb.predict, measures = auc)
```

I was getting an NA value when I tried checking the AUC

```
> performance(nb.predict, measures = auc)
auc 
NA
```

when I tried checking the number of factors for nb.predict

```
test.gender <- as.factor(nb.data$gender)
```

I noticed that it told me that I had 3 factors, the two that I was expecting plus a 3, empty string "". I've checked my data in Excel, I've deleted all of the variables in my environment and rerun my code from scratch. I even tried deleting all of the records except for 2 and I still get a message telling me that I have 3 factors.

What am I doing that is causing an extra factor to be introduced into my code?

Comment: The filtered data only filters out exactly `" "` and `""`, not `"<space><space>"` or `"\n"`, etc.

Comment: @Xorifelse What do I need to do to filter out any empty string?

Comment: @Xorifelse i only have two classes and i know what they are. I also get the same error when I do the filtering in excel and the try to run my model.

Comment: you might try the `strip.white` in the `read.csv()` or change your "filtered_data" to only extract the two specified genders.